No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException with Log4J?
I'm new to Java. I'm building an Selenium application to collect data from some sites and I'm using log4j to log the exceptions, issues and etc. I'm using Microsoft Visual Code to build this aplication.
When I execute the application from MSVC I'm not getting errors. When I execute direct the Jar file I'm getting the error below.
java -jar leilao.jar
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.logging.log4j.plugins.di.NotInjectableException: No @Inject constructor or default constructor found for chain Key[type: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.InterpolatorFactory] -> Key[type: java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.function.Supplier<org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.StrLookup>>; namespace: Lookup]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.plugins.di.DefaultInstanceFactory.createDefaultFactory(DefaultInstanceFactory.java:133)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.plugins.di.DefaultInstanceFactory.lambda$getFactory$3(DefaultInstanceFactory.java:111)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.plugins.di.DefaultInstanceFactory.getFactory(DefaultInstanceFactory.java:111)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.plugins.di.InstanceFactory.getInstance(InstanceFactory.java:126)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.plugins.di.DefaultInstanceFactory.lambda$getArgumentFactory$9(DefaultInstanceFactory.java:211)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:212)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1709)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:556)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:546)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:622)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:291)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:631)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:637)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.plugins.di.DefaultInstanceFactory.lambda$registerBundleMethod$13(DefaultInstanceFactory.java:293)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.plugins.di.InstanceFactory.getInstance(InstanceFactory.java:115)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.<init>(AbstractConfiguration.java:185)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration.<init>(DefaultConfiguration.java:41)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<init>(LoggerContext.java:89)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:289)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:240)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:148)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:131)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:125)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:156)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:49)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:127)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:554)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:540)
        at com.imobiliariavenda.Main.main(Main.java:8)

This is my Pow.xml file.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.imobiliariavenda</groupId>
    <artifactId>imobiliariavenda</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>



    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-beta2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-beta2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>

    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>

This is my log4j2.xml file.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>


This are my build jar log

Whenever you execute any jar file directly at that time you need to configure that jar file into classpath. After that if you will execute then it will execute.
